# Windows service blocking TCP traffic

Tags: windows, service, tcp, blocking

I have a strange issue. Have a windows service running on Windows Server 2008 that receives files over TCP and saves to disk. Initially service was running as Local System account. It worked ok for 7 days and stopped receiving. From the sender side connection succeeds but send fails. The service blocks forever on receive and connection times out.

I changed the user account to "Network Service" and it started working again for 7 days and stopped. I then changed it to run as administrator. It ran for 4 days and stopped again. Now whatever I try it does not work. Rebuilt the code re-installed the service but same issue.

Does anybody ever face such an issue? is it a virus or something? Is windows blocking it? any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Note: If I run it as a windows form application it just works fine. Also disabled the firewall but it did not help. While debugging the code I never see any issues. Because it works as a forms app and also worked perfectly as a service for 15-20 days now.

Comment: Sounds like something code related, you should run it as an application instead of a service and try to debug it.

Comment: Try with the adv firewall service/av software disabled?

Comment: Firewall is disabled and no Antivirus software installed. Running the application inside a windows form has no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When the issue started happening I ran the Filemon utility and figured that the service was failing to access a temp file created using GetTempFileName().

This seems to be a known issue with Windows server 2008R2 and happens randomly.

Here is a solution/Hotfix from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982613

Comment: (Tip: If you click the checkmark to the left of your answer, it'll mark your question as resolved.)